# Alert on gridview edit based on permission

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, gridview

I have a gridview with edit option at the start of the row. Also I maintain a seperate table called Permission where I maintain user permissions. I have three different types of permissions like Admin, Leads, Programmers. These all three will have access to the gridview. Except admin if anyone tries to edit the gridview on clicking the edit option, I need to give an alert like `This row has important validation and make sure you make proper changes`.

When I edit, the action with happen on table called `Application`. The table has a column called `Comments`. Also the alert should happen only when they try to edit rows where the Comments column have these values in them.

`ManLog datas`
`Funding Approved`
`Exported Applications`

**My try so far.**

```
public bool IsApplicationUser(string userName)
{
    return CheckUser(userName);
}

public static bool CheckUser(string userName)
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        string strquery = "select * from Permissions where AppCode='Nest' and UserID = '" + userName + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
    if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1)
        return true;
    else
        return true;
}

 protected void Details_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string currentUser = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
    string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    string[] words = currentUser.Split('\\');
    currentUser = words[1];
    bool appuser = IsApplicationUser(currentUser);
    if (appuser)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(str))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string strquery = "select Role_Cd from User_Role where AppCode='PM' and UserID = '" + currentUser + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, connection);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
        }

        if (e.CommandName.Equals("Edit") && ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Role_Cd"].ToString().Trim() != "ADMIN")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            GridView gvCurrentGrid = (GridView)sender;
            GridViewRow row = gvCurrentGrid.Rows[index];

            string strID = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblID")).Text;
            string strAppName = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblAppName")).Text;
            Response.Redirect("AddApplication.aspx?ID=" + strID + "&AppName=" + strAppName + "&Edit=True");
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly let me know if I need to add something. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool CheckUserAdminOrNot(your arguments)
{
    string currentUser = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
    string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    string[] words = currentUser.Split('\\');
    currentUser = words[1];
    bool appuser = IsApplicationUser(currentUser);
    if (appuser)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(str))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string strquery = "select Role_Cd from User_Role where AppCode='PM' and UserID = '" + currentUser + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, connection);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
        }

        if(user is not Admin)

            return string that you want....
        }
    }
}
```

After that you get response in ajax use this response and redirect page and pass value in url that you want...